# MySQL query with "WHERE title like %post%" returns an empty resultset

Tags: php, mysql

I have started to write a content management system in PHP. I need to run the following SQL query against a database table:

```
select * from blogposts where title like %:term%
```

This query however returns an empty result set and no data is being printed out to a PHP web page. Here is my code:

Database.php:

```
<?php

class Database {

    protected $connection = null;
    protected $statement = null;

    public function openConnection($username, $password) {
        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=content_management_system", $username, $password);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e);
        }
        $this->connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8");
    }

    public function getResultSet() {
        return $this->statement->fetch();
    }

}

?>
```

BlogPosts.php:

```
<?php

include('./Database.php');

class BlogPosts extends Database {

    function __construct() {
        $this->openConnection("stack", "overflow");
    }

    public function getBlogPostsWithTag($tag) {
        $sql = "select * from blogposts where tag = :tag";
        $this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $this->statement->bindParam(":tag", $tag);
        $this->statement->execute();
    }

    public function getBlogPostsWithName($term) {
        $sql = "select * from blogposts where title like %:term%";
        $this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $this->statement->bindParam(":term", $term);
        $this->statement->execute();
    }

}

?>
```

Just so that we are clear, `getBlogPostsWithTag()` works fine, but this very similar `getBlogPostsWithName($term)` doesn't return anything from the database.

search.php:

```
<?php
    include("./BlogPosts.php");
    if (isset($_REQUEST["search"])) {
        $blogpostsTerm = new BlogPosts();
        $blogpostsTerm->getBlogPostsWithName($_REQUEST["term"]);
        while ($resultset = $blogpostsTerm->getResultSet()) {
            echo "<div class='blog-post'>";
            echo "<h2 class='blog-post-title'>" . $resultset["title"] . "</h2>";
            echo "<p class='blog-post-meta'>" . $resultset["created_at"] . " by <a href='#'>" . $resultset["author"] . "</a></p>";
            echo $resultset["lede"];
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I am expecting the method `getBlogPostsWithName($term)` to return some data from the database table, but the actual result is that nothing is being returned/echoed to the PHP web page.

Comment: `like %:term%` needs to be `like '%:term%'` see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) ..

Comment: You need to add the wildcards to the string, not to your placeholder. `title like :term`, then `bindParam(":term", '%'.$term.'%');`

Comment: @aynber I get the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

Comment: Oh, right, because you're using bindParam and not bindValue. Try `$term = '%'.$term.'%';` before the bindParam, then pass in just the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
public function getBlogPostsWithName($term) {
        $sql = "select * from blogposts where title like %:term%";
        $this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $this->statement->bindParam(":term", $term);
        $this->statement->execute();
    }
```

to this:

```
public function getBlogPostsWithName($term) {
        $sql = "select * from blogposts where title like :term";
        $this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $bindingTerm = "%$term%";
        $this->statement->bindParam(":term", $bindingTerm);
        $this->statement->execute();
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

Comment: Try it now, plz.

Answer (score 1):

A placeholder needs to be on its own. Either concatenate the wildcards on the variable, or in the SQL concat the `%`s with the placeholder.

```
$sql = "select * from blogposts where title like :term";
$this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$this->statement->bindParam(":term", $term);
$term =  '%' . $term . '%';
```

or

```
$sql = "select * from blogposts where title like concat('%', :term, '%')";
$this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$this->statement->bindParam(":term", $term);
```

or you could use https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

```
$sql = "select * from blogposts where title like :term";
$this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$this->statement->bindValue(":term", '%' . $term . '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by others, you should have % characters inside the parameter.

```
$this->statement->bindParam("term", "%" . $term . "%");
```

Reason behind it is that the wildcards should be a part of the string. Your result is, however, equal to `like %"blabla"%` which is wrong.

And you don't need a colon in bindParam()

Comment: A parameter can't have assignments. It is only a variable name.